# A question about the set $H^{-1}(\Omega) \cap L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ and it's duality with $H_0^1(\Omega)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, duality-theorems

Let consider $H^{-1}(\Omega)$ as the dual space of $H_0^1(\Omega)$, the classical Hilbert sobolev space with zero traces at $\partial \Omega$. Also, consider $\langle u,v \rangle_{H^{-1}(\Omega),H_0^1(\Omega)}$ as the duality between $H^{-1}(\Omega)$ and $H_0^1(\Omega)$.

Is this true that

$$ \langle u,v \rangle_{H^{-1}(\Omega),H_0^1(\Omega)} = \int_{\Omega} uv \, dx, \qquad \mathrm{for} \,\,\, u \in H^{-1}(\Omega) \cap  L^{\infty}(\Omega), \,\,\, v \in H_0^1(\Omega). $$

Comment: What does it mean that $u\in H^{-1} \cap L^\infty$? If you write this precisely, then the answer is immediate.

Comment: @daw: Do you mean that since each element $u \in H^{-1}$ has a representation as $u=u_0+\sum_{k=1}^{n} (u_k)_{x_k}$ in the sense of distributions, with $u_k \in L^2$, then it follows that $H^{-1} \cap L^{\infty}$ is equal to $L^{\infty}$.